# First url parameter being confounded with all the url address

Tags: javascript, angular, http, url-parameters

I am having an issue with URLSearchParams class with Angular 4.
I try to decompose a url with two parameters:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/actions?uuid=63ieEB&action=signatureBlockClicked
```

This is what I'm doing in my class:

```
export default class MockActionResponse {
  static dispatcher(url, pageModules, ngRedux) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(url);
    const action = params.get('action');
    const uuid = params.get('uuid');
  ……………
```

But the first parameter after the interogation point is `null`, because `URLSearchParams` analyze the url this way.

[image]

Comment: just pass the query string

Comment: `const url = new URL('http://localhost:4200/api/actions?uuid=63ieEB&action=signatureBlockClicked');
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.searchParams.toString());
    const uuid = searchParams.get('uuid');
    console.log(uuid);`

Comment: @AnkitSaroch, you gave me the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer was given to me by @ankit_Saroch. 
I just passed the parameters without the base url!